# Get combinations of list only if one of first element is present

Tags: python

Beginner question.

Given a list of N elements of K characters, all possible output strings such that ith character of output string is from the ith input string.

```
Example:
ex:  N=3 K=2
input = ['ab', 'xy', 'mn']
output =['axm' , 'axn', 'ayn','aym', 'bxm' ,'bxn','byn' ,'bym']
```

As you see the first element in the output is always from the the first string in the output.

Any suggestions would be helpful,thanks in advance.

so this is what i have

```
def foo(K, N, str_list):
    """ 
    K int
    N int
    str_list list[str]
    """
    start_element = str_list[0]
    rem_list = str_list[1:]

    for item in range(N):
      word = rem_list[item]
      for i in range(K):
        print(word[i])  

    return
```

my approach was to take the first element as constant and then loop through other elements ,but its not quite working

Comment: What have you tried? Please post your code.

Comment: i will , one sec

Comment: I don't see 'axy' in the output - in spite of the fact that it does comply with your definition. Is that on purpose? Should the definition be more strict?

Comment: since 'xy' are in the same string ,it will be ignored

Comment: in general the combination should not have more than one element from the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### with itertools

Use `itertools.product`:

```
input = ['ab', 'xy', 'mn']
["".join(x) for x in itertools.product(*input)]
```

result:

```
['axm', 'axn', 'aym', 'ayn', 'bxm', 'bxn', 'bym', 'byn']
```

#### without itertools

One alternative, if one prefers not to use `itertools`, is to use a recursive solution:

```
def cross_prod(l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return [c for c in l[0]]
    else:
        sub_prod = cross_prod(l[1:])
        res = [e + sub_res for e in l[0] for sub_res in sub_prod ]
        return res

input = ['ab', 'xy', 'mn']
print(cross_prod(input))
```

The result, again, is:

```
['axm', 'axn', 'aym', 'ayn', 'bxm', 'bxn', 'bym', 'byn']
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, without using itertools maybe?

Comment: (a) My understanding is that what you're looking for is exactly the definition of cross-product. (b) what's wrong with itertools?

Comment: may be you can give feedback on my approach? let me know if i am on the right path?

Comment: @Ryan - note that there's really no need to pass N and K as arguments. You can deduce them from the list.

Comment: And out of curiosity - do you mind saying why itertools won't work in your use-case? I'm just curious.